# Possible to use count conditional to change channel entry display?

Tags: entries, count

Is it possible to use a count conditional (or equivalent conditional) to change the display of an entry tag depending on how many entries there are?

For example, I have a grid field which I am using for a simple image gallery. I would like to add a condition so that if there is only one entry the image will display as a hero banner, but if there is more than one entry it will change to a gallery.

I wasn't sure if the following (or similar) was possible:

```
{if count > 1}
   <!-- Gallery -->        
{if:else}
   <!-- Hero Image -->          
{/if}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I literally just woke up, but I'm certain you can do what you're asking. If no one picks this up, I'll have an answer for you in a few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly, what you want to do is this :

```
{grid_field}
  {if total_rows < 2}
    {!-- Hero Banner goes here --}
  {if:else}
    {!-- Each Gallery Image displayed here --}
  {/if}
{/grid_field}
```

Note that for what you're asking (if more than one do X else do Y) on a **grid** field you will need to use the [`{total_rows}`](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/grid.html#total-rows) parameter (or for channel entries its [`{absolute_results}`](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#absolute-results)).

Also, note the [parse order](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf). Simple conditionals are parsed before module tags, advanced ones after. I don't think it makes a different but if you're not getting the right results change the `{if total_rows < 2}{if:else}{/if}` to a `{if total_rows < 2}{/if}{if total_rows > 1}{/if}`

Comment: Bastard! :P I wanted to claim this one :)

Comment: ROFL, I so almost put a comment about sniping your awnswer too JChrono ! :P lol, let me find a few of your other answers, a few up votes will soon correct the point difference (PS> I know what your doing, you know I've not been able to get on here much lately, trying to de-throne me on this months points table!) hahahaha